# Media Library broken images

Tags: uploads, media

When I upload image to WP they randomly appear as broken links

I can drop the files on the Media Library or Select the files and some files are always shown as broken.

I can delete the files and re-upload the same group and different images in the group can show as broken.

I'm sure it's nothing to with the images as they sometimes appear as broken and then sometimes don't.

Locally the upload works fine, this problem started happening on the live hosting - I thought it could be something to do with permissions but then wouldn't it show all the images as broken and not show random images as broken.

Comment: There are a host of possible issues here - caching, file permissions, incorrect URL settings... whilst I'd like to help, this question is currently very specific to you (and your hosting).

Comment: TheDeadMedic - could you explain what the URL settings should be ?